# Sybase Advantage Database Server and DATEPART

Tags: sybase, advantage-database-server, datepart

I'm looking to query a Sybase Advantage Database Server using DATEPART. I get an error message that states the following "Scalar function not found: datepart". Is there another function that has similar functionality? I'm looking get a date's quarter. We are currently running version 9.0.

Comment: If you found an answer to your own question, please post it as an answer instead of editing your question to say "SOLVED". It's perfectly acceptable to do so here (see the [faq]), and you can even accept it as correct after a short period of time. Editing to add the solution to your question isn't proper here. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course I find the answer right after posting... For finding the quarter specifically you can use the function QUARTER(*date*).

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage9.0/supported_statements/date_time_functions.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use QUARTER(date) for what you need.

Check [here](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage9.0/supported_statements/date_time_functions.htm) for more information.